# Clearing textContent in Polymer paper-textarea makes control unresponsive

Tags: polymer, paper-elements

I'm trying to clear the text in a polymer paper-textarea element after the input is used.  I am using the following but it clears everything from the input area and renders it unresponsive.

```
<paper-textarea label="New Message" id="txtSendMessage" on-keypress="_keyPressed" value="{{newMessageText}}"></paper-textarea>

_keyPressed: function(e) {
    console.log(e.charCode);
    if (e.charCode == 13) {
        this.sendMessage();
    }
  },

this.$.txtSendMessage.textContent = "";
```

Any ideas on how I can clear just the text?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi just clear its value will do the job.

```
this.$.txtSendMessage.value = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `<paper-textarea>`

```
<paper-textarea id="txtSendMessage"></paper-textarea>
```

To

```
<paper-textarea value="{{message}}"></paper-textarea>
```

And, clear it with JS

```
this.message = "";
```

Whenever you wanted to used an id, ask yourself if what you really need is data binding.

Comment: Sorry, I should have posted more code.  I edited the original submission.  I am using data binding and when the button next to the paper-textarea is pressed it calls this.sendMessage() which clears the newMessageText property which clears the paper-textarea.  The problem occurs in the _keyPressed function.  It calls this.sendMessage() but when the newMessageText property is cleared the paper-textarea isn't affected.  I thought a solution where I clear the paper-textarea manually would be an easy fix.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Or, can you post more code, or make a working test case on plunker?

Comment: I didn't solve it yet.  It seems like when this.sendMessage() is called from the _keyPressed function it acts differently than when it is called from a paper-button's on-tap event.